# Plotly colors the entire world map of a single color

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I tried to create a corographic map about the sismicity level in Sicily using a GeoJSON file with plotly module (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gangelo99/Sismicita-Sicilia/main/classificazione-sismica.geojson). But when I try to show the corographic map, all world is with single color. What I'm supposed to do?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gangelo99/Sismicita-Sicilia/main/classificazione-sismica.geojson') as response:
    polygons = json.load(response)


df = pd.read_csv("dataset_choropleth.csv", dtype={"comune": str})

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=polygons,
    locations='comune',
    # locationmode='country names',
    featureidkey='properties.Comune',
    color="classificazione",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    range_color=(1, 4),
    # scope="europe",
    labels={"aaa"},
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.show()
```

[dataset_choropleth.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gangelo99/Sismicita-Sicilia/main/dataset_choropleth.csv)

This is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLRgC.png)

I tried to set the `featureidkey='properties.Comune'`, but It's seems to not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same event was confirmed, so I looked for another [geojson file](https://github.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/blob/master/geojson/limits_R_19_municipalities.geojson) and replaced the geojson data. After replacing the geojson file, the map was displayed correctly. Perhaps there was a problem with the geojson file, because the map outline provided by `px.choropleth()` is simplified, so it is better to use `choropleth_mapbox()` for this type of map to make the map look better.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

with open('./data/limits_R_19_municipalities.geojson', encoding='utf-8') as response:
    polygons = json.load(response)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gangelo99/Sismicita-Sicilia/main/dataset_choropleth.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0, dtype={"comune": str})

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=polygons,
    locations='comune',
    featureidkey='properties.name',
    color="classificazione",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    range_color=(1, 4),
    labels={"aaa"},
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

**px.choropleth_mapbox()**

```
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df,
    geojson=polygons,
    locations='comune',
    featureidkey='properties.name',
    color="classificazione",
    color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    zoom=6,
    center={'lat': 37.50000,'lon': 15.090278},
    range_color=(1, 4),
    labels={"aaa"},
)
```

[image]